# Filling out WebForm without "finding element by..." Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webforms, automation

I am very new to selenium webdriver and I'm using python. I want to go to a webpage that contains(textbox, dropdowns, radio buttons, etc) and I want to tab/move from element to element w/o a "driver.find" syntax because that would defeat the purpose of automating, for some of these pages have a lot of fields. Is there a way to tab from one element to another, without getting the element's id?

Essentially, I would tab from field to field and create an if statement: If this is 'input' then do this, else if 'select' do this, etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated? I hope I was clear?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you can do this!  I will use an example for something with checkboxes:

```
checkboxes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@type="checkbox"]')

        for allChecks in checkboxes:
            try:
                allChecks.click()
            except:
                print("Checkbox not working")
```

So this finds every element that is a checkbox and checks it.  with `allChecks.click()`.  Notice a couple of things though as when I was learning they were really subtle and I missed.

When finding one element on a page you want to use `find_element_by_xpath` to find multiple elements on a page use `find_elements_by_xpath` notice that elements is plural in the second one.

Comment: Thank you so much @Morgan G.  Worked great.